# Inline function versus normal select

Tags: sql-server-2012, table-valued-parameters

Now I am studying about functions in SQL Server 2012. I knew that there are three function types. But I am confused by `Inline Table-Value Functions`.

Let me explain.

```
select * into Number 
from (
 values 
  (1, 'A'),(2, 'B'),(3, 'C')
) number (N, C)

create function InlineFun (@i int)
returns table
as
return (select * from Number where n = @i)

select * from Number where n = 1
select * from InlineFun (1)
```

From the above `select`'s the results are the same. Then what is the exact scope of `Inline TVF`..?

Note :

I am using `Microsoft SQL Server 2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of an `ITVF` as a `view` you can pass parameters to.  It is essentially included in your script that references it as if it was plain old SQL and then executed.  This is why they perform better than multi statement table valued functions, which have to be executed as a seperate statement.

Due to this, in your examples the statement:

```
select *
from InlineFun (1)
```

Is essentially passed to the query engine as:

```
select *
from (select *
      from Number
      where n = 1
     ) as a
```

So to actually answer your question, the scope of the function is the same as the scope of the statement that calls it.

Comment: so, there is no daze scope for `ITVF`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "daze scope"

Comment: Sorry @iamdave Just I tried a phrase using Google. What I meant that __there is no special scope for ITVF__

Comment: @IdontKnowEnglish That is correct.  If my answer was what you were looking for, please mark it as such for other users with the same question in the future

Comment: I will ask more about `SQL Function`. Keep supporting.